# How do you say "I would do myself a disservice" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

I have checked multiple dictionary entries and their examples regarding this sound extremely unnatural. How would you say "I would do myself a disservice, if _____________" in German?

Comment: Can you please provide an example sentence and state what exactly you're trying to convey?

Comment: Yes. Let's suppose that I want to buy a bag. How do I say, I would do myself a disservice if I did not buy that bag?

Comment: In my dictionary it says " to do oneself/sb a disservice:  sich / 
jdm einen schlechten Dienst erweisen". I think this sounds unnatural

Comment: @hehe "sich/jdm einen schlechten Dienst erweisen" doesn't sound unnatural at all.

Comment: Ok then I will use that one.

Comment: In fact "schlechter Dienst" is perhaps the closest possible translation to "disservice". "Service" (Dienst) exists, but "disservice" as a word ("Nichtdienst") simply doesn't exist in German.

Comment: I don't see that the question can be answered without context, since there is no close counterpart. With the example from the comment, I would not use *disservice* (i.e. doing something which has not the desired effect, for which the German *Bärendienst* is a convincing translation) for a lack of action (like **not** to buy a bag) for English either.

Comment: We need those unnatural sounding examples, to convince you, they're not or to agree and avoid repeating them.

Comment: @guidot - Wiktionary also gives "Bärendienst" as a translation of "disservice". I don't know if that's very common or not, but it's a fun word (lit. "bear service").

Answer (score 6):

You can say

> Ich würde mir selbst keinen Gefallen (damit) tun, wenn ...

Literally meaning

> I wouldn't do my myself a favor, if ...

Comment: One could add that while this is an excellent translation for most cases, it doesn't fit the context of *not* buying a bag very well, because one would hardly use "to do oneself a favor" (sich einen Gefallen tun) with *not* buying something.

Answer (score 3):

The two suggestions "Ich würde mir einen schlechten Dienst erweisen, wenn ..." and "Ich würde mir keinen Gefallen (damit) tun, wenn ..." do the job, but I doubt that one would use them in the context of buying a bag. In my opinion one should say something like

- Ich müsste dumm sein, wenn ...
- Ich würde mir selbst schaden, wenn ...

Comment: I think the second one is closer to the original tone. I'd render the first as "I'd be stupid if I (didn't buy that bag)." Which is certainly something someone might say, but using "disservice" is more formal sounding.